# How to popup modal when i choose a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am trying to popup a modal when i click on a specific date.
My code is this. When i choose a date nothing happens and i dont know why

```
<input type="date" id="startdate1"name="startdate1"required>

 <div class="modal fade" id="fileUploadModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add Comment</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p><textarea id = "commentsUpload"class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitXYX()" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script >
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#startdate1" ).change(function() {
      $('#fileUploadModal').modal('show')
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: You code works totally fine, have you added boostrap js and css correct and after jquery?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen what you see is what i wrote and have i dont know what is the problem

Comment: Yes i can see what you wrote, please show me where you have included bootstrap and jquery and at what order. Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/aqyw7xzh/

Comment: Thanks a lot i included wrong src and that did not work, i used the one that you provided me and it works just fine, thanks a lot again!